# Fixed DIV throughout the website with changing URLs and content, but fixed DIV must stay without reloading

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making a radio streaming website using PHP. I need to keep my audio-player DIV static throughout the website. I need to changing URLs and page content, **but player DIV must stay without reloading**. This is something smiler to HTML frames in old days.  My solution must also be search engine friendly. I'm really appreciate if some can help me with this.

I search everywhere to find an exact solution for this problem. But did not able to find something that clear enough for me.

**Page structure is something like this**

```
<div id='main_wrap'>
 <div id="header">

  <!-- Titles and other content. Different on each page. -->

 </div>
 <div id="player">

  <!-- Flash live audio streaming player. same throughout the site. Shouldn't reload for constant playback-->

 </div> 
 <div id="footer">

  <!-- Other content. Different on each page. -->

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AJAX is fundamental and simple to learn along with jQuery, and if you go through that you will be confident to solve your problem and many other in your career.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a few options, you could use HTML5's built in history which will only work on selected browsers and then use Ben Alman or Jquery Address as a fallback for other browsers that don't support HTML5 history